# Подскажите, как лучше оформить класс

Tags: c#, .net, проектирование

В общем, хочу сделать класс, который будет импортировать DataTable в Access или MS SQL.

Класс будет иметь 1 метод: Append, которому на вход будет подаваться DataTable, а метод в свою очередь будет загружать DataTable в нужный пункт назначения.

Разумеется, внутренняя логика Append у Access может сильно отличаться, например:

1. В Access нужно следить за тем, что бы файл не был выше 2гб, иначе бд поломается
2. В MS SQL можно воспользоваться BulkCopy, а в Access потребуется какой-то самопал.

Соответственно и конструкторы могут сильно отличаться по параметрам, например:

1. Строки подключения между двумя типами будут отличаться
2. В MS SQL можно использовать или не использовать транзакцию
3. В Access можно восстанавливать или не восстанавливать БД после каждого Append.

Как лучше всего все это оформить?

**UPD:**

Есть у меня некоторые предположения, как это можно сделать, но не знаю на сколько это верно.

Сделать интерфейс:

```
 public interface IApend
    {
         void Append(DataTable dt);
    }
```

Реализовать его в 2 ух классах, каждый из которых будет содержать в себе собственную логику импорта:

```
       public class ImporterToSQL: IApend
    {
        //Какие-то поля
        public void Append(DataTable dt)
        {
            //Какая-то логика
        }
    }
    public class ImporterAccess : IApend
    {
        //Какие-то поля
        public void Append(DataTable dt)
        {
            //Какая-то логика
        }
    }
```

И создать такой класс:

```
   public class Importer
    {
        IApend Concrete;

        public Importer(IApend concrete)
        {
            Concrete = concrete;
        }
        static Importer ImporterToSQL(object v,object v2,object v3)
        {
            return new Importer(new ImporterToSQL(object v, object v2, object v3));
        }
        static Importer ImporterToSQL(object v, object v2)
        {
            return new Importer(new ImporterToSQL(object v, object v2));
        }
        static Importer ImporterToAccess(object v, object v2, object v3)
        {
            return new Importer(new ImporterAccess(object v, object v2, object v3)));
        }
        static Importer ImporterToAccess(object v, object v2)
        {
            return new Importer(new ImporterAccess(object v, object v2));
        }
        public void Append(DataTable dt)
        {
            Concrete.Append(dt);
        }
    }
```

На сколько это верно и на сколько хорошо этот подход будет работать в плане добавления нового функционала(Например, мне приспичило добавить импорт из SQL в Access)? Это , вроде, зовется фабрикой классов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути. Общий интерфейс для конвертации -- это правильно. Только я бы назвал его чуть поконкретнее, хотя б `IImporter` какой-нибудь.

Что касается создания конкретных экземпляров и вашего класса `Importer`. Для создания действительно нужна фабрика. Однако она у вас получилась не в чистом виде. Смысла оборачивать экземпляр в ваш `Importer` нет -- у вас уже есть интерфейс. Просто создавайте нужные экземпляры и возвращайте их. А клиент уже будет вызывать напрямую методы:

```
public static class ImporterFactory
{
    static IImporter CreateSQLImporter(object v, object v2, object v3)
    {
        return new ImporterToSQL(v, v2, v3);
    }

    static IImporter CreateAccessImporter(object v, object v2, object v3)
    {
        return new ImporterAccess(v, v2, v3);
    }

    // и так далее
}
```

В качестве параметров для конструкторов у вас наверняка выступают специфичные для каждой реализации данные: например, строка подключения для SQL и путь к mdb файлу для Access. В идеале клиент вообще не должен знать что-то о деталях реализации, а фабрика должна содержать один метод на тип. Все детали о реализации прячутся в фабрике, которая подсовывает нужные параметры напрямую из конфигурации (например, из app.config). При этом клиент вообще ничего не будет знать о реализации:

```
public static class ImporterFactory
{
    static IImporter CreateImporter(object v)
    {
        var generalConfig = GetGeneralConfig();
        if (generalConfig.Type == "sql")
        {
            var config = GetSqlImporterConfig();
            return new ImporterToSQL(config.ConnectionString, v);
        }
        else if (generalConfig.Type == "access")
        {
            var config = GetAccessImporterConfig();
            return new ImporterToAccess(config.ConnectionString, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Такой подход будет очень хорошо работать, если вам потребуется импорт в новое место. Вы просто напишете еще одну реализацию `IImporter`, внести изменения в `ImporterFactory` и все. Все клиентs, которые используют `IImporter`, менять не придется. В случае же отдельных методов вам придется менять вызывающий код, который управляет тем, какой метод вызвать.

---

Что касается импорта из SQL в Access, то такую задачу описанным выше способом не решить. Выше мы рассмотрели только задачу "как данные, представленные в универсальном виде (DataTable), записать в конкретное место". Задачу импорта из SQL в Access можно переформулировать как "как извлечь данные из одного места и записать их в другое место". Такую задачу полезно разбить на два шага и ввести промежуточный этап. Какой? Правильно, получение данных в универсальном виде. Таким образом, шага будет два:

1. Импорт из источника с преобразованием в универсальный вид
2. Экспорт в другое место

Соответственно, два основных контракта будут выглядеть как-то так:

```
interface IImporter
{
    DataTable Import();
}

interface IExporter
{
    void Export(DataTable data);
}
```

Реализация второго шага у вас уже есть, правда сейчас она называется импортом. При наличии двух шагов будет логичнее назвать их с т.з. того, как данные движутся относительно *вашего приложения*. Вы импортируете (загружаете) данные из одного источника и экспортируете (выгружаете) их в другое место.

Реализация первого шага будет аналогична -- различные реализации интерфейсов, фабрика.

Для осуществления процесса конвертации вам понадобится некоторая общая сущность, которая будет соединять шаги. Она может принимать в качестве зависимостей как фабрики, так и экземпляры импортера/экспортера:

```
public class DataConverter // придумайте имя поудачнее, пожалуйста :)
{
    private readonly IImporter _importer;
    private readonly IExporter _exporter;

    public DataConverter(IImporter importer, IExporter exporter)
    {
        _importer = importer;
        _exporter = exporter;
    }

    public void Convert()
    {
        var data = _importer.Import();
        _exporter.Export(data);
    }
}
```